# What can I say about the maps $\text{Spec} (A / \mathfrak{a}) \to \text{Spec} (A)$ geometrically?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was curious whether there is a general approach to say something about the geometric interpretation of the maps $\text{Spec}(A / \mathfrak{a}) \to \text{Spec}(A)$ for a commutative ring with unity $A$.

I ask this because I'm trying to solve an exercise, which asks me to "describe geometrically" all maps $\text{Spec}(\mathbf{C}[X] / (X^2) ) \to \text{Spec}(\mathbf{C}[X, Y])$, and I don't really know how to start there. (Of course $\mathbf{C}[X] / (X^2)$ is just a single point. The question in that particular case is probably, where it gets mapped.)

Comment: Do you know about tangent spaces in this context?

Comment: I'm also assuming these are going to be $\mathbb C$-morphisms. In that case it would be good to first describe all maps from the spectrum of $\mathbb C$ to the plane. In fact some of your maps in the original question will factor through this, so it's good to try first.

Comment: Exercise II.2.8 in Hartshorne answers your question, but leaves you with the details.

Comment: You can think of Spec(A) as the "geometric space on which elements of A are functions," and Spec(A/I) as the "geometric space on which elements of A/I are functions.  On the level of points, this may simply be regarded as the set of points of Spec(A) on which all elements of I vanish, since this means that elements of $A/I$ have well-defined values on them. Of course, your question is about schemes that see more than just points...the answer then is the business about tangent vectors mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The map $Spec(A/a)\rightarrow Spec(A)$ induced by the quotient morphism $A\rightarrow A/a$ is the embedding of $V(a)=Spec(A/a)$ in $Spec(A)$ where $V(a)$ is the set of prime ideals containing $a$.

Comment: Well, this is quite clear I guess. But what about the *geometric meaning*?

Comment: What do you mean by geometric meaning? for me, embedding is a geometric meaning